# How to Index new keywords

Tags: seo, google-search-console, metatag

My question is I had changed My Websites Keywords and submitted it to the google i.e verified by the google MetaTag. and Google is indexing that keywords. I have changed my keywords, But google indexing older keywords not the recent keywords, 
 Will I need to re-verify by the google MetaTag
or please suggest me any other solution which will index my new keywords

Answer (score 0):

The google crawler doesn't run everyday. Sometimes it can take up to a week for new keywords to be indexed. It's just a matter of waiting. They'll show up.

If you have pages where the content changes frequently, when you provide google with your sitemap, you can stipulate this. A simple tool that will auto generate this for you is http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

Just alter the change

Answer (score 0):

The keywords meta tag is not important. Search engines don't pay any attention to it anymore. I wouldn't waste my time worrying about.

Here's a quote from SEOmoz's Beginner Guide to SEO (http://guides.seomoz.org/chapter-4-basics-of-search-engine-friendly-design-and-development): "The meta keywords tag had value at one time, but is no longer valuable or important to search engine optimization."

Instead, I would worry about making sure the content on your site is well-written, relevant to your topic, and keyword-focused (but not keyword-crammed...sound natural). Make sure your title tags are appropriate to what's on each page. That will get you farther than meta keywords.

Additionally, it takes time for search engines to index changes. Be patient on any changes you make to your site.