# How to re index new keywords

Tags: seo, google-search-console

My question is I had changed My Websites Keywords and submitted it to the google i.e verified by the google MetaTag. and Google is indexing that keywords. I have changed my keywords, But google indexing older keywords not the recent keywords, Will I need to re-verify by the google MetaTag or please suggest me any other solution which will index my new keywords

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  What do you mean with google tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Index new keywords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633455/how-to-index-new-keywords)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about webmaster tools (Google MetaTag): no you don't need to resubmit, google will find it on it's own.

If you are talking about the robots metatag: no you don't need to resubmit, google will find it on it's own.

If you are talking about the "keywords" tag: don't use it (http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/keywords-meta-tag-in-web-search/)

Answer (score 0):

It will take some time to index your keywords. You can make change in on page factors such as fresh content but make sure about keyword density.